# cannot use a different controller with a view with ui-router AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, angular-ui-router

I'm using ui-router for routing my angular app. I have the following route:

```
'use strict';

//Setting up route
angular.module('admins').config(['$stateProvider', 
    function($stateProvider) {
        // Admins state routing
        $stateProvider.
        state('admin_home', {
            url: '/admin',
            templateUrl: 'modules/admins/views/list-admins.client.view.html'
        }).
        state('adduser', {
            url: '/admin/create',
            templateUrl: 'modules/admins/views/create-admin.client.view.html', 
        }).
        state('viewAdmin', {
            url: '/admins/:adminId',
            templateUrl: 'modules/admins/views/view-admin.client.view.html'
        }).
        state('editAdmin', {
            url: '/admins/:adminId/edit',
            templateUrl: 'modules/admins/views/edit-admin.client.view.html'
        });
    }
]);
```

This is within my 'Admin' module, and that has its own controller (AdminsController).

However, I want to be able to create a new user from here, and the controller to do that is called 'AuthenticationController' and is elsewhere in the structure.

As far as I know, I should be able to put something like:

```
state('adduser', {
                url: '/admin/create',
                templateUrl: 'modules/admins/views/create-admin.client.view.html',
                controller:'AuthenticationController'

            })
```

and it should work.

However - I keep getting redirected back to the index page.

I suspect this may be because I'm using HTML5 and have this in my config also:

```
// use HTML 5
         $locationProvider.html5Mode(true).hashPrefix('!');
            //Sets the HTTP header type for the redirects
           $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common = {
            'Accept': 'application/json', 
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: Assuming you're trying to directly load `/admin/create`, have you set up the necessary server-side URL rewriting for HTML5 mode? See https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#how-to-configure-your-server-to-work-with-html5mode

Answer (score 0):

You should add  :

```
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/home");
```

And declare your controller inside your state function (not in your view files) like that :

```
 state('viewAdmin', {
        url: '/admins/:adminId',
        controller : AdminsController,
        templateUrl: 'modules/admins/views/view-admin.client.view.html'
 })
```

If it doesn't work, try to remove :

```
 $locationProvider.html5Mode(true).hashPrefix('!');
            //Sets the HTTP header type for the redirects
 $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common = {
     'Accept': 'application/json', 
     'Content-Type': 'application/json'
```

Let me know ;)